# Combining object operator ( -> ) and "new"

Tags: php

Given a class A with a member function f(), the following apparently reasonable code:

```
( new A() )->f();
```

Fails with a syntax error: "unexpected T_OBJECT_OPERATOR".

Is there an explanation for this?

Edit: As Mageek guessed, I'm trying to make sense of this behaviour; I already know how to work around it.

Comment: why not just do $a = new A();  $a->f();      ?  or A::f();

Comment: @JohnB Surely, his goal here is not to make it work but to understand

Comment: I'm not sure you can do that sort of thing with PHP (at least up to version 5.3). You can do it in something like C#, but not PHP.

Comment: Kind if silly to not have this behavior IMO.

Comment: TaZ: Not an explanation for me. Sorry.

Comment: Chiyou : Not a comment for me. Sorry. (:P)

Comment: If you'd like to have a better understanding of this kind of behaviour (and why everyone here seems to agree that it's logical), take a look at [functional programming](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Functional_programming). It's quite related to this kind of stuff.

Comment: Chiyou: What is the value of "new A()"?  An object instance, right?  Therefore, it stands to reason that it should be possible to invoke its methods.

Comment: array($mydata) is also an example and practical example not from a textbook.

Comment: @neptes: So, it's with array($mydata); it can make $mydata an array?

Comment: Chiyou: I don't understand how that's a comparable example.

Comment: The explanation is that it's just not in the language spec until 5.4

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is only available as of PHP 5.4. Until then you have to assign the instance to a variable and use that.

See: http://www.php.net/manual/en/migration54.new-features.php

Comment: Thanks.  Since the syntax is now allowed, I guess I'll chalk it up to an oversight in the parser for versions up to and including 5.3.

Answer (score 0):

The feature you have asked for is available from PHP 5.4. Here is the list of new features in PHP 5.4:

http://docs.php.net/manual/en/migration54.new-features.php

> Class member access on instantiation has been added, e.g. (new Foo)->bar().

---

But you can try this trick:

```
class TestClass {
    protected $_testvar;

    public function __construct($param) {
        $this->_testvar = $param;
    }
    public function testMethod() {
        return $this->_testvar;
    }
}

function TestClass($param) { return new TestClass($param); }
```

Now you can write:

```
$a = TestClass(2)->testMethod();
```